# Glusterfs brick size

Tags: glusterfs

I'm trying to deploy a gluster cluster with 12 nodes with 10 TB each one, but when I create the volume each brick is created with only 50GB, it must have the entire disk space i suppose. This is my config:

Disk config in each node:

```
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0   9,1T  0 disk 
└─sda1            8:1    0   9,1T  0 part /bricks/brick1
```

Gluster volume info:

```
Volume Name: vol01
Type: Distributed-Replicate
Volume ID: 70de6c08-e133-406e-99b0-7284be67cf5f
Status: Started
Snapshot Count: 0
Number of Bricks: 6 x 2 = 12
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: gfs01:/glusterfs/distributed
Brick2: gfs02:/glusterfs/distributed
Brick3: gfs03:/glusterfs/distributed
Brick4: gfs04:/glusterfs/distributed
Brick5: gfs05:/glusterfs/distributed
Brick6: gfs06:/glusterfs/distributed
Brick7: gfs07:/glusterfs/distributed
Brick8: gfs08:/glusterfs/distributed
Brick9: gfs09:/glusterfs/distributed
Brick10: gfs10:/glusterfs/distributed
Brick11: gfs11:/glusterfs/distributed
Brick12: gfs12:/glusterfs/distributed
Options Reconfigured:
transport.address-family: inet
nfs.disable: on
performance.client-io-threads: off
```

Brick's volume detail (only 2 of them, rest have same config):

```
Brick                : Brick gfs01:/glusterfs/distributed
TCP Port             : 49152               
RDMA Port            : 0                   
Online               : Y                   
Pid                  : 12308               
File System          : xfs                 
Device               : /dev/mapper/centos-root
Mount Options        : rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota
Inode Size           : 512                 
Disk Space Free      : 48.4GB              
Total Disk Space     : 50.0GB              
Inode Count          : 26214400            
Free Inodes          : 26152769            

Brick                : Brick gfs02:/glusterfs/distributed
TCP Port             : 49152               
RDMA Port            : 0                   
Online               : Y                   
Pid                  : 11446               
File System          : xfs                 
Device               : /dev/mapper/centos-root
Mount Options        : rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota
Inode Size           : 512                 
Disk Space Free      : 48.4GB              
Total Disk Space     : 50.0GB              
Inode Count          : 26214400            
Free Inodes          : 26152770
```

Client mount point (50*12=300GB):

```
gfs01:/vol01                              300G    13G  288G   5% /mnt/glusterfs
```

Any idea? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the disk for the brick is mounted at `/bricks/brick1`. But you created the volume based on a different directory for the bricks, namely `gfs01:/glusterfs/distributed`.

You should probably create a new volume, like this:

```
# gluster volume create lotsofdata \
  replica 2 \
  gfs{01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12}:/bricks/brick1/data

# gluster volume start lotsofdata
```

Make sure that `/bricks/brick1` is mounted automatically (through `/etc/fstab` or a `systemd.mount`). You should then be able to mount the new volume called `lotsofdata` and copy the contents from `vol1` to there.

Currently your `vol1` is using the space from the `/dev/mapper/centos-root` logical volume. So you will want to remove `vol1` and all of the `/glusterfs/distributed` directories.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! I can't believe I didn't notice that!